# "imspossible" error on a simplest code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm trying to run and i can't. Maybe it's connected with pointers, 
i've lost the expectation.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
float createMatrix( int N )
{
    int i,j;
    float **matrix;
    matrix = new float*[N];
        if (matrix == NULL)
        {
            free(matrix);
            return 0;
        }
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        matrix[i] = new float[N];
    for(i=0; i<N;i++)
        for(j=0; j<N;j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rand();
    return **matrix;
}
void printMatrix (float **matrix)
{
    int N = sizeof(matrix)/sizeof(float);
    for(int i=0; i<N;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<N;j++)
            std::cout << (matrix)[i][j];
    std:: cout << std::endl;
    }
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int N=0;
    std::cout << "Hello! Please, write any number for a size of the matrix\n";
    std::cin >> N;
    float m = createMatrix(N);
    printMatrix(m); // error
    return 0;
}
```

Error: No matching function to compile 'printMatrix'
Please, help me!

Comment: `printMatrix` expects `float**` but you're passing `float`

Comment: In addition to `float createMatrix( int N )` leaking memory (and _creating_ a single `float` instead of `float` matrix).

Comment: why does `printMatrix` takes a pointer to pointer? What are you trying to do? you pass a `float` and expect a `**float!!`

Comment: `new float*[N]` never returns null, and if it did, `free(nullptr)` is invalid.

Comment: @aschepler _`free(nullptr)` is invalid_ No. As explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free): _If ptr is a null pointer, the function does nothing._

Comment: `free()` should only be used with a pointer returned by `malloc()`. If you use `new`, you have to free it with `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to return from this function a pointer to pointer to float. But you return now just first value.

```
float** createMatrix( int N )
{
    int i,j;
    float **matrix;
    matrix = new float*[N];
        if (matrix == NULL)
        {
            free(matrix);
            return 0;
        }
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        matrix[i] = new float[N];
    for(i=0; i<N;i++)
        for(j=0; j<N;j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 5; // not just rand(), in this case you become numbers in range [0, max int)
    return matrix;
}
```

And then by storing your matrix too. A pointer should be stored, not the first value.

```
float **m = createMatrix(N);
```

Next line will give you always 1. It is because `matrix` is a pointer and all pointers have size 4 bytes. So you have 4 / 8 == 1.

```
int N = sizeof(matrix)/sizeof(float);
```

In case with raw dyn arrays we need to pass the size as a parameter.

```
void printMatrix(float **matrix, int N) { /* do work */ }
```

Finally you call this function so.

```
printMatrix(m, N);
```

But in C++ you should use `std` and dont care about all these pointers, that look actually terrible. `std::vector` does that work for us.

**EDIT 1:**
As was corrected in comments, not all pointers have 4 bytes size. At 64-bit systems it haves 8.

**EDIT 2:**
We should not forget to free memory:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    delete m[i];
}
delete[] m;
```

Comment: _ It is because matrix is a `pointer` and all pointers have size 4 bytes_ Not correct. What is the size of the pointer on 64-bit system?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius you have right. Pointer can be 8 bytes also. And not always 8 too. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: `free(matrix)` should be `delete[] matrix`

Comment: @Barmar not just `delete[] m;` but
 `for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      delete m[i];
  }
  delete[] m;`